# Error on MySQLi DB Trigger w/ Case Statement

Tags: mysqli, triggers

I am working on my first DB trigger and having an issue. The trigger involves a case statement and I am getting the error #1054 - Unknown column 'ORDERTYPECODE' in 'field list'.

The ORDERTYPECODE is a column on the table from which the trigger is called. Do I need to define which table the column belongs too?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `StartNewIncOrderProcessing` AFTER INSERT ON `T_ORDERS` 
FOR EACH ROW CASE WHEN ORDERTYPECODE = 'INC' THEN 
INSERT INTO T_INC_DATA (ORDERID) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ORDERID) FROM T_ORDERS));
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `StartNewIncOrderProcessing` AFTER INSERT ON `T_ORDERS`

    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.ORDERTYPECODE = 'INC' THEN
    INSERT INTO T_INC_DATA (ORDERID)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ORDERID) FROM T_ORDERS ));  
    END IF;
```

END